# Python get URL from Apache

Tags: python, apache, python-2.7

I am using Apache2 as my webserver and mod_python as the "interpreter" for it. How can I pick up the current url parameters? For example: /cgi-bin/test.py?set=12

I want to make actions based on the posted values in the URL. I looked at the `urlparse` library, but that requires the URL, which I do not have yet.

Comment: `mod_python` is dead and buried. Use [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) instead.

Comment: Indeed - better yet than using directly mod_wsgi (which is authored by the ex-last-maintainer of mod_python) - you would be better using a framework for Python web applications than trying to tie one script to the web server using nothing but the web server plug-in for Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def index():  
    return "Python works!"

def command(command):  
    return "this is a command %s!" %command
```

Index returns string when calling page as normal

test.py/command?command=foo will return foo